# Irrational and rational sequence proof

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

> Show that every irrational number in $\mathbb{R}$ is the limit of a
>   sequence of rational numbers. Every rational number in $\mathbb{R}$ is
>   the limit of a sequence of irrational numbers.

How can I prove this?

Comment: Do you know that both $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R - \Bbb Q$ are dense in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Given an irrational number $x$, can you think of a set of interval $I_i$ containing $x$ and such that the end points of $I_i$ are always rational and the lengths of the intervals $I_i$ tend to 0 as $i$ tends to infinity?

Comment: From destiny real numbers proprty every rational number lies between two irrational numbers so there is two sequences of  irrational numbers one of them increasing and bounded by this rational number as supermum of this sequences and another sequence is decreasing also bounded by the same rational number as infomum all these sequences has limit at this rational number. Is easy to prove that which mean write these sequences by A general mathematical formula,.. inversing is right but is ont easy formulate sequences because the irrational numbers is not contuble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is to prove that $\Bbb Q$ and $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ are dense in $\Bbb R$. This means (equivalently) that for every pair of reals $x,y$ there exist $r\in\Bbb Q$ and $\ell \in \Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ such that $$x<r<y$$ and $$x<\ell<y$$

For the first, I give you some hints: Hover over the grey areas for extra, possibly spoiling, hints.

$(1)$ Assume that $y-x>1$. Prove there exists an integer $m$ between $x,y$

> Look at $\lfloor x\rfloor +1$.

$(2)$ Now, let $x,y$ be such that $y-x>0$. The archimedean property of $\Bbb R$ means that  there exists $n$ such that $n(y-x)=ny-nx>1$. Use $(1)$

> There exists an integer $m$ between $ny,nx$, from where $nx<m<ny$ or $$x<\frac m n z y$$ and we have found our rational number.

$(3)$ Here, we might use that, say $\sqrt 2$ is irrational. Then since $\sqrt 2 <2$, $\frac{\sqrt 2}2<1$. Then we start with an irrational $\mu\in(0,1)$. Given two rationals, $r,s$ with $r-s>0$, we have that $$0<\mu(r-s)<r-s$$ so that $$s<s+\mu(r-s)<r$$

It suffices to prove that $s+\mu(r-s)$ is irrational. Can you do this?

All the above proves that $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ are dense in $\Bbb R$. Can you see why?

Now, if I give you an irrational (or irrationals) $\lambda$, look at the intervals of the form $$\left(\alpha-\frac 1 n,\alpha +\frac 1n \right)$$

and build a sequence of rationals (resp. irrationals) converging to $\alpha$.

Comment: @Q.matin You're welcome. Glad it helped.

Comment: Peter, so to prove this I just have to essentially show that rational and irrational are dense, and that will complete the proof?

Comment: @Q.matin If by "this" you mean that any irrational is the limit of a rational sequence and vice versa, yes.

Comment: One last question, I dont understand what I have to do with $\left(\alpha-\frac 1 n,\alpha +\frac 1n \right)$?

Comment: Well, for each $n$, we can find a rational $r_n$ (we use the subindex to mark the fact we relate each $n$ to a rational $r_n$) for which $r_n\in \left(\alpha-\frac 1 n,\alpha+\frac 1n\right)$. But since $\lim\frac 1 n=0$, what can you say about $|\alpha-r_n|$? for large $n$? We are constructing an appropriate sequence of rationals $\langle r_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, see?

Comment: Hmm, nope I cant see.

Comment: Well, since $r_n\in \left(\alpha-\frac 1 n,\alpha+\frac 1n\right)$, we have that $\alpha-\frac 1 n<r_n<\alpha+\frac 1n$. This means that $-\frac 1 n<r_n-\alpha<\frac 1n$, i.e. $|r_n-\alpha|<1/n$. But for any $\epsilon >0$, we can find $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $1/N<\epsilon$ (and thus $1/n<\epsilon$ for $n\geq N$). By the definition of limit of a sequence, $$r_n\to\alpha$$ since we can make $|r_n-\alpha|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$ for any given $\epsilon$.

Comment: Ohhh, wow that is a nice technique. I just couldnt see that. I need to study some more. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Q.matin Practice, practice, practice.

Answer (score 8):

Let $\alpha$ be irrational. For each positive integer $n$ there is a least integer $k$ such that $\dfrac{k}{n} > \alpha$, and then this number is rational. You need to prove that this sequence tends to $\alpha$.

Now let $\alpha$ be rational, and repeat the above argument with something like $\dfrac{k\sqrt{2}}{n}$ instead of $\dfrac{k}{n}$. [You'll also need to prove that $\dfrac{k\sqrt{2}}{n}$ is irrational whenever $k \ne 0$, and cook up a way of avoiding having $0$ in the sequence.] **Edit:** Or consider $\alpha+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ or something like that, as Cameron Buie suggests in the comments.

The moral of the story is that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \mathbb{Q}$ are [dense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (+1): It's even easier than that in the second case. If $\alpha$ us rational, then $\alpha+\frac\pi n$ is irrational for all positive integers $n$, and this sequence converges to $\alpha.$

Comment: Oh yes, that's much more simple, thanks!

Comment: Alright, thanks guys! I am going to try and attempt now.

Answer (score 6):

For the first, take more and more digits of the decimal expansion.

For the second, if your number is $a$, take $a+e, a+e/10, a+e/100, \ldots$