# Density of irrationals in rationals

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the irrationals are dense in the rationals: for all rational numbers
$x < y$ there exists an irrational $\alpha$ such that $x < \alpha < y$.

I know that between any two real numbers there exists an irrational number.
Proof:  Let $x < y$ be two real numbers.  Then $x - \sqrt{2}$ and $y- \sqrt{ 2}$  are also real numbers. There is a rational number $r$ such that $x - \sqrt{2} < r < y- \sqrt{ 2} $ .  Adding $\sqrt{2}$ to both sides of these equations, and we have $r + \sqrt{ 2 }$.  We know that $r$ is rational and $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational Therefore $r + \sqrt{ 2 }$ is an irrational number between two arbitrary real numbers, and hence the claim.
Will the proof done with rationals follow the same steps, considering that  rational numbers should be written in the form $p/q$ where $p, q \in\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $x$ and $y$ which can be mistaken for real numbers?

Comment: Rational numbers are real numbers.

Comment: Rational numbers are in particular real numbers. So nothing need change.

Comment: Odd phrasing; the irrationals aren't even *in* the rationals, so how could they be dense in the rationals? Fortunately, the question clarifies what is meant.

Comment: Is there another way for proof like using fractions instead of assuming that rational numbers as real numbers.

Comment: @Avinesh: The problem doesn't even make sense unless you consider it in the context of the real numbers.

Comment: is this what you want? «if I knew only about rational numbers (that is, fractions) and found out that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational, may I show that there is a number not rational between any two fractions?»

Comment: I wanted to see if irrationals could be dense between x and y, where x and y be written as a fraction (p/q).

Comment: This question is similar to mine. Take a look: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338328/irrational-and-rational-sequence-proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $x=\dfrac{p}{q}$ and $y=\dfrac{m}{n}$ Here ($p,q)=1$ and $(m,n)=1$

$x^2= \dfrac{p^2}{q^2}$

$y^2= \dfrac{m^2}{n^2}$

Now can you find rational numbers between them ? You can infinitely many rational numbers between $x^2$ and $y^2$ of the form $\dfrac{p_i}{q_i}$ where $(p_i,q_i)=1$

Now $ ( \dfrac{p_i}{q_i})^\frac{1}{2}$ is a irrational.(Why?), these lie between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: This what i was looking for. Thanks for your time kind help.

Comment: @Avinesh It's funny that you were looking for this more complicated proof when the proof you gave in your question actually is a competely valid proof of the statement already. Any special reason for that?