# Does square root of quotient of two numbers of gcd = 1 is Irrational.

Tags: real-analysis

Let x = p/q where (p, q) = 1

then square root of p/q is irrational. Is the statement true or false?

Comment: @André Nicolas so with side conditions i.e considering the gcd = 1, then the statement is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely false without side conditions, take $p=q=1$. Or take $p=4$, $q=9$.

But one can prove that if $\gcd(p,q)=1$, then $\sqrt{p/q}$ is irrational unless $p$ and $q$ are perfect squares.

To do this, suppose that $\sqrt{p/q}$ is the rational number $a/b$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers, without loss of generality relatively prime.

Then $pb^2=qa^2$. Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, we have $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$ (proof not difficult).

From $pb^2=qa^2$, we see that $p$ divides $qa^2$. Since $\gcd(p,q)=1$, $p$ divides $a^2$. Also, from $pb^2=qa^2$, we see that $a^2$ divides $pb^2$. Since $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$, it follows that $a^2$ divides $p$.

Thus $p=a^2$ and therefore $q=b^2$.

Comment: Greatest Common Divisor (p, q) = 1

Comment: That is (or was) my preferred notation also. But nowadays, $\gcd(p,q)=1$ seems to be more common. Some people have tried to popularize the notation $p\perp q$, without much success.

Comment: You are welcome. I thought that the response "it's not necessarily true" that I gave at the beginning, though correct, was insufficient when a full theorem can be proved. But maybe the two counterexamples at the beginning are all you are looking for.

Comment: I was trying to verify the answer given to me on my previous question on density of irrationals. Do you agree with the answer given on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345469/density-of-irrationals-in-rationals

Comment: The $\left(\frac{p_1}{q_1}\right)^{1/2}$ there could be rational. There **will** be irrationals of that type, but that has not been proved. I saw your question, did not answer it because I remember a similar question that was answered. Sorry not to provide a link, but I am not good at searching. If you can't find a proof on MSE, I will give one, but not today, it is quite late.

Comment: Thanks for your time and kind response. Will be looking forward for your response on densities of irrationals.

Comment: @Avinesh: I looked at your proof. It is fine, and proves the density result fully. Mine was basically the same. Let $x\lt y$. There is a rational $r\ne 0$ between $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}$. Then $x\lt r\sqrt{2}<y$. No improvement on yours.

Comment: Thanks for verifying my answer.

Comment: From $pb^2=qa^2$, we see that $p$ divides $qa^2$. When I read this I didn't get how it is concluded! For a minute I was just like How! How How!...$\text{60 times}$.Though, it is very Natural. Since $p\vert pb^2$ so that, $p\vert qa^2$.