# How to Calculate Irrational Numbers

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers

I would like to understand how to "calculate" irrational numbers. By that I mean, how did an irrational number come into existence. In order to understand that, I guess I am wondering what the structure of every irrational number is (if *all* are an infinite series, or various other things). By knowing the structure of all irrational numbers I should be able to calculate them. I am thinking in terms of symbolically modeling them on a computer.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate"? Do you mean, by a series of rational numbers, like $\pi=4(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-+\cdots)$?

Comment: Do you mean how to find the value of an irrational number?

Comment: Yeah to find the value, yes, by series if that's what it is. I don't know if _all_ irrational numbers are series, for example.

Comment: you can usually find them with the help of an infinte series . for example $e = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$. This is usually done by setting specific values in a functions Taylor series

Comment: Any real number between $0$ and $1$ has a series expansion of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n/10^n$ where each $a_n\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Answer (score 2):

You "can't find seem to find an example", but there are very nice series for, say, $\sqrt{2}$ here:

[Infinite series for $ \sqrt 2 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694699/infinite-series-for-sqrt-2)

In general, every irrational number can be written as the limit of the sum of rational numbers:

[Is it possible to represent every irrational number as a (limit of) an infinite sum of rational numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466622/is-it-possible-to-represent-every-irrational-number-as-a-limit-of-an-infinite)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. That's exactly what I was wondering but didn't know how to put it.