# Disprove $f(x)$ continuous using Heine

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $g(x)$ be defined at $x_0$, $D(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & x \in \mathbb Q\\ 
0 & x \notin \mathbb Q
\end{matrix}\right.$ - Dirichlet function.

Let $f(x) = g(x)D(x)$.

Prove that if $g(x_0) \neq 0 \Rightarrow f$ is not continuous at $x_0$ using Heine definition.

---

So i think that i need to show that: 
$\exists(x_n)^\infty_{n=1}, x_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty}x_0: \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) \neq f(x_0) $.

How can i find that $x_n$?

Comment: What is Heine definition?

Comment: That is how i understand it,


Heine definition for limit: $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = L:$


$ \forall (x_n)^\infty_{n \to \infty} (x_n \neq x_0), x_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty}x_0 \Rightarrow  f(x_n) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty}f(x_0)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now $f(x_0)=g(x_0)D(x_0) =\begin{cases}
g(x_0) & \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$

Case 1: $x_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$, by density of real number, for every rational number we have sequence of irrational numbers $x_n$ such that $x_n \to x_0$. Now $f(x_n)=g(x_n)D(x_n)=0$ cannot $\to f(x_0)=g(x_0) \neq 0$.

Case 2: Again by density of real number, for every irrational number we have sequence of rationals $x_n \to x_0$, so $f(x_n)=g(x_n)$. If $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)=0$ then $g_(x_n) \to g(x_0)=0$ contradiction.

Comment: Isnt it better to show exactly the serie? i mean explicitly: $x_n =...$? How do you explain that there is a serie that converge to $x_0$? you just say so

Comment: It depends on your $x_0$, the density property only tells us the existence of the sequence.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: I dont realy convinced. You just say

Comment: You can see here for more detail https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338328/irrational-and-rational-sequence-proof